# how to use solr with mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, search, solr

i read about how i could use solr to search in my threads but i dont quite understand how it works and i cant find any articles explaining this for a total beginner.

could someone explain briefly how solr works and how it communicate with mysql and php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First take a look at [this tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html).

With solr you will need to have an xml (or [csv](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV)) document which will be pushed to solr (process is called updating; indexing is the process to make fields available for search). The format of xml is sth. like:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">9885A004</field>
    <field name="name">Canon PowerShot SD500</field>
    <field name="category">camera</field>
    <field name="features">3x optical zoom</field>
    <field name="features">aluminum case</field>
    <field name="weight">6.4</field>
    <field name="price">329.95</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

Look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages) for more details.

But in your case you could use a crawler (appropriated if different or external sources) to get different document formats recognized.
Try to understand if [Nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/about.html) could help here.

E.g. take a look at [this presentation](http://www.danielnaber.de/publications/jazoon07_naber.pdf) for an explanation about solr, lucene and nutch.

Comment: Good answer but I don't see anything in the question that suggests the OP needs a crawler.

Comment: ok, true. I thought he mentions php, because of some external services / cms